# How to overwrite devise redirection when updating password?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I would like to allow user to update his password. When it's done I Want it to be redirect on the same page.
I don't want to use the `redirect_to :back` (I would like to avoid 500 error.)

My problem is that the update is in many steps in the view.
You can click on button "edit profile" 
url = http://localhost:3000/fr/u/edit#profil

or on button "edit password" url = http://localhost:3000/fr/u/edit#password

The controller is `users/registrations, action update`

I tried to overwrite devise method with :

**users/registrations_controllers**

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

 def update
  super
 end

protected

  def after_update_path_for(resource)
    redirect_to edit_user_registration_path + "##{password}"
  end
end
```

when the form has no errors I have this error :

> > Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return".

When the form got errors : I'm redirect on the edit_registration_path#profil

What can I do to be redirected on the previous password page anyway ?

Comment: Write only this line edit_user_registration_path + "##{password}", remove the word redirect.

Comment: Good ! I do not have the error anymore. When the form has no error it's ok I'm redirected on the edit password page. But when there are errors I'm still redirected on #profil. Do you have idea on how to manage error ?

Comment: For this, you have to overwrite the update method.

Comment: Do you have an example ?